# Get all keys in Dictionary containing value x

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dictionary

I have this:

```
Dictionary<integer, string> dict = new Dictionary<integer, string>();
```

I want to select all the items in the dictionary that contain the value `abc`.

Is there an inbuilt function that lets me do this easily?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Well it's *reasonably* simple with LINQ:

```
var matches = dict.Where(pair => pair.Value == "abc")
                  .Select(pair => pair.Key);
```

Note that this won't be even slightly efficient - it's an `O(N)` operation, as it needs to check every entry.

If you need to do this frequently, you may want to consider using another data structure - `Dictionary<,>` is specifically designed for fast lookups *by key*.

Comment: You could if you want to get the keys that have a value that contains "abc" you could also:

var matches = dict.Where(pair => pair.Value.Contains("abc"))
                  .Select(pair => pair.Key);

Comment: @User: `Dictionary<,>` is just shorthand for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. How big is your dictionary? How many values do you need to search for? Once per second isn't very often, if it's a reasonably small dictionary and you're only looking for a single value...

Comment: The dictionary's capacity is 10 keys and 4 values ("Left","Right","Front","Back"). And sometimes the function runs about 10 times per second.

Comment: For such a small collection you shouldn't worry, However, if you don't use the special indexing feature of Dictionary you might be better off with a List<Tuple<int, string>>.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Which data structure would you recommend then?

Comment: @stephanmg: I'd need to know more about the precise requirements. If you *have* such requirements, I suggest you ask about that in a new question, with details.

Comment: @JonSkeet: You are right. I'd assume the OP wanted a "bidirectionally" fast access. In this case one could use a second dictionary in which key/val pairs are inverted.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in function? No sorry... but another (not so beautiful) way is to iterate using `foreach(KeyValuePair<integer, string> ...`