# How to Get all keys in Dictionary having same value without using LINQ

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have this:

```
Dictionary<integer, string> dictTempKeys = new Dictionary<integer, string>();
```

I want to select all the keys in the dictionary that contain the same value.
I can do this by using LINQ as :

```
var duplicateValues = dictTempKeys.GroupBy(xx => xx.Value).Where(xx => xx.Count() > 1);
```

Answer for this with LINQ is already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146048/get-all-keys-in-dictionary-containing-value-x), but I dont want to use LINQ in my code, as I would be using this code in C# CLR Stored Procedure and that doesn't support LINQ. So is there any other approach I could attain this?

Comment: You could use a simple for loop

Comment: @BugFinder But it would destroy the main usage of dictionary, its speed. Is there any extension method that i could use?

Comment: You want to select only keys or the pairs key,value?

Comment: It's not possible without a full scan. The values in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` are not indexed, only the keys are.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov I want only those values which are appearing more than once in dictTempKeys.

Comment: @dymanoid Ok, so what could be the fastest approach to get all the values appearing more than once?

Comment: " I want only those values which are appearing more than once in dictTempKeys" - For what reason? Smells like X-Y-Problem.

Comment: @Fildor Like I said, I would be using this code in C# CLR Stored Procedure and that doesn't support LINQ.

Comment: Yes but use it to do *what*?

Comment: @Fildor Ok lemme explain you the whole scenario. First I have taken all the keys from another dictionary of objects and stored into this dcitionary dictTempKeys as values. These keys earlier were combination of certain fields and I have taken only a part of those keys, thats why there could be multiple similar at first place.

Comment: When you don´t want to or can´t use any Linq-code you *have* to use classic for/foreach, which is actually the same as all the Linq-methods do internally as well. To identify duplicates in your dictionary you of course *have* to iterate the elements.

Comment: Alright, from all the comments, I came to conclusion that I would use classic foreach for my scenario. Thanks everyone for their valuable comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my attempt - a generic extension method.
The first `foreach` loop traverses the source dictionary and transforms it to a lookup where the keys are the values from the source, and the values are integers indicating the occurrence count of source's values in the source dictionary.

The second `foreach` loop will give you an `IEnumerable` using the `yield return` statement.

```
public static IEnumerable<TValue> GetNonUniqueValues<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
{
  Dictionary<TValue, int> results = new Dictionary<TValue, int>();
  foreach (var kvp in source)
  {
    int count;
    if (results.TryGetValue(kvp.Value, out count))
    {
      count++;
    }
    else
    {
      count = 1;
    }

    results[kvp.Value] = count;
  }

  foreach (var kvp in results)
  {
    if (kvp.Value > 1)
    {
      yield return kvp.Key;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `foreach` loop and reverse your dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> keysByValue = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> entry in dictTempKeys {
    List<int> keys;
    bool hasKeys = keysByValue.TryGet(entry.Value, out keys);
    if (!hasKeys) {
        keys = new List<int>();
        keysByValue.Add(entry.Value, keys);
    }
    keys.Add(entry.Key);
}
```